# Does anyone know of a simple yet flexible 2d scene graph in c++?

Tags: c++, graph, 2d, scene

I'm searching a simple 2d scene graph written in c++, possibly on top of OpenGL but that's not mandatory: the perfect thing would be the Cocos2d/Cocos2d-iphone scenegraph in c++.
Do you know of any existing implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ideas:

- [SGL](http://sgl.sourceforge.net/) - It is designed for 3D scene graphs, but also might support 2D. The website looks pretty informative.
- [Papyrus C++ Cairo Scenegraph Library](http://libpapyrus.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Papyrus seems interesting, i didn't know about it, but it seems quite pretty.

Answer (score 1):

[y60](http://y60.artcom.de) by artcom might have 2D stuff, too.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg) handles both 3D and 2D Scenes and sits on top of OpenGL.  We use it here at work and have gotten a lot out of it.  Quite powerful and multi-platform as well.